# Apply `a -> Maybe b` function to `Maybe a`

Tags: haskell

Say I have a function `parse :: String -> Maybe (Integer, String)` that parses the first integer `i` from a list of integers encoded as a string `s` like `1,2,3` and returns `Just (i, s')` where `s'` is the remaining string or `Nothing` if parsing failed.

How can I then concisely apply this function to a `Maybe String`? `parse <$> maybeString` has redundant type `Maybe (Maybe (Integer, String))` and writing a custom pattern matching function for this seems to be overkill.

More generally: is there an equivalent to `<$>` of type `(a -> f b) -> f a -> f b` (or would that not make sense?).

EDIT: I'm stupid, I just realized there's Hoogle for this. Is this what we need Monads for? (I haven't reached that part of Haskell yet).

Comment: Yes, this is what `Monad`s are for. You want the `parse` function to run conditionally depending on the argument (run it if the argument is `Just x`, skip if it the argument is `Nothing`). The possibility of skipping or not skipping the invocation of (applicative/monadic) functions depending on data is what makes `Monad` more powerful than `Applicative`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `(>>=)` which you can use like `maybeString >>= parse`. This requires the data type you're working with to be a Monad which `Maybe` satisfies.

Comment: That makes sense, so Monads are a "superclass" of applicative functors, right?

Comment: @Peter almost! A Monad is more general than an applicative functor (everything you can do in a Monad, you can do in an applicative functor). In the newer versions of GHC, you are required to provide an applicative instance for your Monads (`class Applicative m => Monad m where`)

Comment: @ymegdiche I assume this was a typo, but your statement is potentially misleading - a Monad is actually *less* general than an Applicative. Every Monad is necessarily an Applicative, but not vice versa.

Comment: @RobinZigmond indeed, thanks! A Monad is more specialized than an applicative functor. Can't edit the comment for some reason though