# Destructuring `Maybe (a, b)`

Tags: haskell

Sort of a followup to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455876/apply-a-maybe-b-function-to-maybe-a/65455913#65455913). I'm going through Brent Yorgey's Haskell course and I'm trying to solve an exercise that asks us to create an instance of `Applicative` for the following type:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }
```

`runParser` parsers a string and returns a token and the remaining string. `p1 <*> p2` should in this case apply a function generated by `runParser p1` to the token generated by `runParser p2` (applied to what's left of the string after running `runParser p1`).

So far I have:

```
(Parser { runParser = run }) <*> (Parser { runParser = run' }) = Parser run''
  where run'' s = (first <$> f) <*> (s' >>= run')
          where f = fst <$> run s
                s' = snd <$> run s
```

`(first <$> f) <*> (s' >>= run')` seems pretty concise to me, but the nested `where`'s and the weird destructuring of `run s` look "off". Is there a nicer way to write this?

Comment: Minor style note: `Parser { runParser = run }` is a pretty unidiomatic way of destructuring a `newtype`. More usual is to simply call it `p` or something, and then use `runParser p` to get to the function inside.

Comment: You can derive `Applicative` via `StateT String Maybe` using DerivingVia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me rewrite this a bit to avoid pattern matching:

```
p <*> q = Parser run
  where run s = (first <$> f) <*> (s' >>= runParser q)
          where f = fst <$> runParser p s
                s' = snd <$> runParser p s
```

Here, I’ve simply used the field accessor `runParser :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (a, String)` instead of directly pattern-matching on the arguments. This is considered a more idiomatic method of accessing `newtype`d functions in Haskell.

Next, there are some obvious simplifications which can be made, particularly inlining some functions:

```
p <*> q = Parser $ \s -> (first <$> f) <*> (s' >>= runParser q)
  where
    f = fst <$> runParser p s
    s' = snd <$> runParser p s
```

(Note that `s` now has to be explicitly passed to the functions in the `where` block so they can access it. Don’t worry, I’ll get rid of this in a minute.)

One confusing thing in this implementation is the nested applicatives and monads. I’ll rewrite that section slightly to make it a bit clearer:

```
p <*> q = Parser $ \s ->
    let qResult = s' s >>= runParser q
    in first <$> f s <*> qResult
  where
    f s = fst <$> runParser p s
    s' s = snd <$> runParser p s
```

Next, let’s get rid of those annoying `f` and `s'` definitions. We can do this using pattern-matching. By pattern-matching on the output of `runParser p s`, we can access these values directly:

```
p <*> q = Parser $ \s ->
    case runParser p s of
        Nothing -> Nothing 
        Just (f, s') ->
            let qResult = runParser q s'
            in first f <$> qOutput
```

(Note that, since `f` and `s'` are no longer in `Maybe`, much of the applicative and monadic plumbing which was required before is now unneeded. One `<$>` still remains, since `runParser q s'` can still fail).

Let’s rewrite this slightly, by inlining `qResult`:

```
p <*> q = Parser $ \s ->
    case runParser p s of
        Nothing -> Nothing 
        Just (f, s') -> first f <$> runParser q s'
```

Now observe a pattern in this code. It does `runParser p s`, fails if this fails; otherwise it uses the value in another computation which can fail. This just sounds like monadic sequencing! So let’s rewrite it with `>>=`:

```
p <*> q = Parser $ \s -> runParser p s >>= \(f, s') -> first f <$> runParser q s'
```

And finally, the whole thing can be rewritten in `do`-notation for readability:

```
p <*> q = Parser $ \s -> do
     (f, s') <- runParser p s
     qResult <- runParser q s'
     return $ first f qResult
```

Much easier to read! And what makes this version particularly nice is that it’s easy to see what’s going on — run the first parser, get its output and use it to run the second parser, then combine the results.

Comment: Great answer, now I also finally understand what `do` is actually good for.

Comment: @Peter Glad I could help! `do` really is amazingly useful when you fully understand how it works.

Answer (score 5):

In my eye, there's no shame in keeping it simple using basic pattern matching only, without relying too much on `<*>`, `<$>`, `first`, and other library functions.

```
Parser pF <*> Parser pX = Parser $ \s -> do
   (f, s' ) <- pF s
   (x, s'') <- pX s'
   return (f x, s'')
```

The above `do` block is in the `Maybe` monad.